# MySQL Sum Problem

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have table a and b.

- a has order_id and ship_total
- b has order_id, item, qty, and price

How do I query and get the sum of all ship_total on all orders that have a total qty under 100?

I am afraid if I do something like this, it's going to be wrong.

```
select SUM(ship_total) FROM a as a inner join b as b on a.order_id=b.order_id WHERE SUM(qty) < 100 GROUP BY a.order_id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried the answers from below and it's not adding everything together.  It's giving me the shipping amount from each order.

Comment: In other words (contrary to the current list of answers), what you really want is the grand-total of all the orders, not separate totals of the individual orders.

Comment: @X-Zero This is correct.

Comment: I inadvertently added a `GROUP BY` to my answers earlier, but have removed them now. Give them a shot and let me know if they don't do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT
    SUM(A.ship_total)
FROM
    (SELECT B.order_id FROM B GROUP BY B.order_id HAVING SUM(qty) < 100) SQ
INNER JOIN A ON
    A.order_id = SQ.order_id
```

Another way:

```
SELECT
    SUM(A.ship_total)
FROM
    A
WHERE
    order_id IN (
        SELECT order_id
        FROM B
        GROUP BY order_id
        HAVING SUM(qty) < 100)
```

Try each out and see which performs best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. When you want to limit results that are aggregated, you need to use the `HAVING` clause.

```
select SUM(ship_total) 
FROM a as a 
inner join b as b 
  on a.order_id=b.order_id 
GROUP BY a.order_id
having SUM(qty) < 100
```